# counting unique value pairs in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like the below:

```
           place          user     count  item
2013-06-01 New York       john     2      book
2013-06-01 New York       john     1      potato
2013-06-04 San Francisco  john     5      laptop
2013-06-04 San Francisco  jane     6      tape player
2013-05-02 Houston        michael  2      computer
```

I'm trying to count the number of unique `(date, user)` combinations for each `place` — or, put another way, the number of 'unique visits' to each city. So for 
`New York` it would be one, for `San Francisco` it would be two, and for `Houston` it would be one.

I've tried doing the below follows:

`df.groupby([df.index, user, place]).place.size()` but that just returns the total `count` for each place. I feel like I'm missing something really obvious here, but I can't see what it is. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it, assuming you convert the index to a column named date, but you can also just pass it in like you show above.

Input:

```
df.groupby(['place', 'user', 'date']).place.count().groupby(level='place').count()
```

Output:

```
place
Houston          1
New York         1
San Francisco    2
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternative answer:

```
df.drop_duplicates(['date', 'place', 'user'])['place'].value_counts()
```

It is a bit more efficient than Phillip's answer (because in general groupby is not):

```
In [64]: %timeit df.groupby(['place', 'user', 'date']).place.count().groupby(level='place').count()
100 loops, best of 3: 2.55 ms per loop

In [65]: %timeit df.drop_duplicates(['date', 'place', 'user'])['place'].value_counts()
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.27 ms per loop
```

(figures calculated on the DataFame above concatenated 10000 times).

("drop_duplicates" is also useful if one wants to enumerate the different combinations - assign an id to each - rather than just count them, although this is not the case in the OP's question)